# Python requests automate form submission thrustcurve.org

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to automate the process of search ThrustCurve.org.

As an example, if I go to this page: http://www.thrustcurve.org/searchpage.jsp and set Impulse Class to "F" and click "Search" a list of results is then displayed.

I'd like to automate this activity with requests, but have been unsuccessful.

Here's what I've tried:

```
formdata = {'impulseClass': 'F',
            'sortBy': 'inpulse_class'}
r = requests.post("http://www.thrustcurve.org/motorsearch.jsp", data=formdata)
```

This results in a server error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Now I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get to page 2 of results. The website appears to only provide a maximum of 50 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you have a typo in the value for `sortBy`. Using `'sortBy': 'impulse_class'` works for me.

Comment: even after fixing that type, my problem was that I needed to use the `json` keyword instead of `data`. Thanks!

Comment: any ides on getting past the first 50 results of a search?

Comment: @flutefreak7 The `data` keyword was alright. Passing the specifiers as `json` makes them ineffective. Regarding the 50 items limitation, the website doesn't seem to return more than 50 items. You should narrow your query in order to get below 50 items. Querying for `'impulseClass': 'F'` yields 41 items for me.